# Como colocar um CSS dentro da tag html com URL?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho esse **CSS** que gostaria de colocar no meu `form`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

Porém, quando coloco no `<head>` o **CSS** de toda página é alterada (obviamente iria acontecer isso).

Como faço para **importar** esse **CSS** somente para a **tag** `<form>`?

Comment: Esse link é toda a biblioteca de css do w3. quando você coloca na tag head é normal a alteração. Uma coisa que você pode fazer é criar uma página somente para o form! sem precisar das tags html, body, head.. Apenas o form. E ai sim na página do body passar o CSS do w3

Comment: Eu criei, porém, continua _alterando_ coisas como o **menu**. Queria colocar esse css só na **tag** `form`, como faço? @BrunoCastro

Comment: Por quê não cria o seu CSS próprio e estiliza o `form` da maneira que deseja?

Comment: tem como mostrar seu código? E a pagina do w3 que usa esse css

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss porque achei bonito o **CSS** do _W3 Schools_, e queria fazer algo simples porque é uma página de exemplo.

Comment: Basta vc abrir o link e copiar as partes do css que você deseja usar no seu form. Por ex: as formatações de button,input,select,textarea e etc.

Comment: não tem como colocar este css só na tag form. Ele é o css completo do w3. Se você optar por usar deste link, vai ter que usar todos os estilos aplicados pelo w3. Agora, uma forma de manter o seu próprio estilo utilizando o css do w3 é adicionar o !important dentro do seu próprio estilo. exemplo: .elemento1{background-color: #f0f !important}

Comment: De repente se vc colocar o seu css depois desse do w3 pode ser que dê certo devido a prioridade em css. PODE SER e não VAI SER.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo funcionou cara! Obrigado

Comment: Vai virar resposta então

Comment: Veja a resposta que publiquei e aprenda um pouco sobre prioridade em css e aproveita e leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> De repente se vc colocar o seu css depois desse do w3 pode ser que dê certo devido a prioridade em css. PODE SER e não obrigatoriamente VAI SER.
>    "têm prioridade aquelas declaradas por último"

### Prioridade de Estilos (cascata)

Em alguns casos você pode especificar diferentes estilos para a mesma página por meio da combinação de um arquivo ".css" referenciado em link ou com a inserção de uma tag de style, e também com atributos de estilo inline. Se estas diferentes especificações entrarem em conflito entre si, o browser tem que decidir qual dos valores deve usar. Essa escolha é feita com base numa ordem de prioridade (cascading style sheets - "folhas de estilo em cascata").

**Esta ordem de prioridade segue assim:**

- default
- do Browser
- CSS externo (arquivo ".css")
- CSS interno (dentro da tag )
- Estilos inline (dentro do elemento HTML )

Então, um estilo inline tem a maior prioridade dentro da "cascata", o que significa que ele irá fazer um override sobre todo estilo declarado dentro da tag , em um arquivo externo ".css", e em um browser (valor default).

[**FONTE**](http://www.ggte.unicamp.br/minicurso/css/texto/Modulo1/mod001tela004.htm)

> O ideal seria você incorporar na sua folha de estilos somente as partes do css que você deseja usar no seu form como bem disse o nosso amigo **alan** no comentário e que lhe trará somente benefícios.

Quando uma pessoa entra no site pela primeira vez, os primeiros segundos são críticos para captar a atenção e convencê-la a ficar mais um pouco ou a voltar no futuro. Se o seu site demora muito tempo a carregar, a maioria das pessoas desiste e abandona-o, mesmo antes de ter tido oportunidade de lhes mostrar o valor do seu serviço. “Um atraso de um segundo pode resultar em 7% menos conversões, 11% menos visualizações de páginas, ou mesmo uma diminuição de 16 por cento na satisfação do cliente" [BRYAN EISENBERG](http://www.bryaneisenberg.com/how-your-website-loses-7-of-potential-conversions/).

**Código limpo significa carregamento mais rápido e visitantes contentes.**

É importante manter o tempo de carregamento baixo escrevendo código semanticamente adequado, usando as melhores práticas de otimização de performance e, rotineiramente, a limpeza de CSS, HTML e imagens.

Geralmente, o tempo de carregamento do site irá aumentar com sua evolução e isso, de certo modo, é algo já esperado. Por isso é importante fazer essa rotina de limpeza de HTML, CSS e imagens uma parte natural do fluxo de trabalho para garantir uma experiência positiva ao usuário.

Comment: Existe também o !important que da prioridade máxima para o estilo

Comment: se você constrói suas regras ........

Comment: E tem a outra metade da cascata, que determina a precedência conforme o seletor.

Comment: PODE SER e não obrigatoriamente VAI SER. Mas o autor ficou satisfeito e deu certo.